# Pshat of what did Korach take?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parshat-korach

In Parashat Korach ([Bamidbar 16:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.16.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)):

> וַיִּקַּ֣ח קֹ֔רַח בֶּן־יִצְהָ֥ר בֶּן־קְהָ֖ת בֶּן־לֵוִ֑י וְדָתָ֨ן וַאֲבִירָ֜ם בְּנֵ֧י אֱלִיאָ֛ב וְא֥וֹן בֶּן־פֶּ֖לֶת בְּנֵ֥י רְאוּבֵֽן׃
>   ב וַיָּקֻ֙מוּ֙ לִפְנֵ֣י מֹשֶׁ֔ה וַאֲנָשִׁ֥ים מִבְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל חֲמִשִּׁ֣ים וּמָאתָ֑יִם נְשִׂיאֵ֥י עֵדָ֛ה קְרִאֵ֥י מוֹעֵ֖ד אַנְשֵׁי־שֵֽׁם׃
>
> Korach, son of Yitzhar, son of Kehat, son of Levi and Datan and Aviram sons of Eliav and On son of Pelet son of Reuven took.
>   And they, 250 heads of the nation, people of status stood before Moshe and people of Bnei Yisrael...

What did Korach take? It doesn’t say anywhere in the following pesukim, and Rashi only says that there is a Midrash on this, but he doesn’t quote it. What do the other Mefarahim say about this?

Note: I’d like to keep the focus on the story so please no g’zeira shava type of thing which teaches something unrelated.

Comment: Consider Shoftim 14:11 or Shmuel 2:18:18

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/33463/25248

Comment: I liked the question you asked in your (now deleted) comment. I looked around a bit and couldn't find an answer, so went ahead and asked it here. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105232/why-does-rashi-preface-his-comments-by-saying-the-medrash-explains-this-well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen the problem of the apparently-missing object of this sentence addressed in the following ways:

[Targum Yonatan](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01591.html#HtmpReportNum0015_L2) claims that he took **his garment which was כולה תכלת.** (Note that the section immediately preceding the story of Korach, which is about the requirement to put ציצית with a strand of תכלת on the corners of garments, and recall also the Midrash in which Korach challenges Moshe by asking whether a garment that is completely תכלת requires ציצית or not.)

> וּנְסֵיב **גוּלְיָיתֵיהּ דְכוּלָא תִּיכְלָא** קרַח בַּר יִצְהָר בַּר קְהָת בַּר לֵוִי וְדָתָן וַאֲבִירָם בְּנֵי אֱלִיאָב וְאוֹן בַּר פֶּלֶת בְּנֵי רְאוּבֵן

Targum Yerushalmi says that he **took counsel** and split off.

> **ונסיב עצה** ופלג קרח

The Gemara in Sanhedrin קט: claims that he **took a bad deal (מקח) for himself**

> ויקח [קרח] אמר ריש לקיש שלקח מקח רע לעצמו

Midrash Tanchuma suggests, among other things, that he **took the leaders** in with soft words

> ויקח. אין ויקח אלא **משיכת דברים רכים, שמשך כל גדולי ישראל** והסנהדראות אחריו

and in addition suggests that **his heart took him.** (That is to say that the *object* of the sentence is present (קרח) but the *subject* is absent.)

> ויקח קרח, אין ויקח אלא לשון פליגה, **שלבו לקחו**, כענין שנאמר, מה יקחך לבך ומה ירמזון עיניך (איוב טו יב)

(The Midrash Tanchuma also mentions the idea seen above about taking his טלית and about taking counsel.)

Rav Saadiah Gaon (in the תורת חיים edition's back-translation of his Arabic translation of the Torah) thinks **Korach didn't take anything.** He translates ויקח as "**he approached**."

> ויקח: **ויגש**

[Rashi](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=4&perek=16&mefaresh=rashi), as you've already seen, and as mentioned by @JoelK, cites Targum Onkeles's translation of ואתפלג and explains that **he took himself** to the side, separating himself from the nation

> ויקח קרח. **לקח את עצמו** לצד אחד להיות נחלק מתוך העדה לעורר על הכהונה, וזהו שתרגם אונקלוס ואתפלג,

and as we saw in the Tanchuma, that he **took the leaders with words**

> דבר אחר, ויקח קרח, **משך ראשי סנהדראות שבהם בדברים**, כמו שנאמר קח את אהרן (במדבר כ, כה), קחו עמכם דברים (הושע יד, ג)

[Rashbam](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/tnh_text.asp?rash=1&id=273) and some of the other baalei pshat think the answer *is* in the following pesukim: He states that Korach, together with דתן ואבירם, **took many people - the 250 men** mentioned in the next pasuk.

> ויקח קרח, כמו ויקח אברם את שרי אשתו ואת לוט, אף כאן ויקח קרח ודתן ואבירם **אנשים הרבה,** עד שקמו עמהם לפני משה חמשים ומאתים

(And [Bechor Shor](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40226&pgnum=90) agrees that he took people, and says that this first pasuk can be short in this way because it's right next to the pasuk giving the details, and [Seforno](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=4&perek=16&mefaresh=sforno) also takes this route.)

> דתן ואבירם ואון, — שהיו ראשי המחלוקת לפי שקרח שהיה לוי היה מתרעם על הכהונה, ובני ראובן על שהיה ראובן בכור אמרו שיש להם דין בכהונה **ולקחו את האחרים** ופיתום להיות עמם כדכתיב ויקמו לפני משה ואנשים מבני ישראל חמשים ומאתים שלקחו ומשכו עמם,
>   וקצר בפסוק ראשון כי סמך על הפסוק השני וכן דרך אפילו בשתי פרשיות שמקצר בראשון מפני שסומך על פרשה שנייה

[Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.16.1?lang=he&with=Chizkuni&lang2=he) offers the possibility that the ו in ודתן is to be ignored, so that **he took דתן ואבירם ואון בן פלת בני ראובן**.

> ויקח קרח, לשון לקיחת אנשים, ומי לקח: דתן ואבירם בני אליאב ואון בן פלת בני ראובן. וי"ו ד"ודתן" יתירה היא, וכמוה יש הרבה

[Ramban](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01586.html#HtmpReportNum0015_L2) mentions this approach and offers an example of a pasuk in which the vav is ignored ("ואלה בני צבעון **ו**עיה וענה (בראשית לו כד)") but ultimately says ignoring the vav is unnecessary, and that לקיחה can just be a word used to describe initiating an action of some kind

> ולפי דעתי אין צורך כי הגון הוא בלשון שיאמר ויקח קרח ודתן ויקומו ויקהלו על משה ועל אהרן כי **בכל תחילת מעשה תבא לקיחה והוא לשון התעוררות במעשה ההוא** וכן ואבשלום לקח ויצב לו בחייו את מצבת

The Alshich thinks he **took his lineage** - that is, he took his status as בן יצהר, which motivated him to rebel. (This motivation is mentioned in the Tanchuma, and also pointed out by the Abarbanel, but neither of them seem to explicitly connect it to the question of what Korach took.)

> והנה אמרו רבותינו ז"ל שאמר קרח, אחי אבא ארבעה היו, עמרם ויצהר כו. בני עמרם נטלו שררה, אחד מלוכה ואחד כהונה גדולה. השררה השלישית למי היה, לא לבני יצהר שהוא שני לעמרם. ולמה מינה את אלצפן בן עוזיאל הקטון לנשיא הקהתי. ובזה מצה מקום לערער גם על הכהונה. ואפשר על פי דרך זה, כי זה יאמר ויקח קרח **מה לקח הלא הוא היותו בן יצהר,** כי על כן אליו נוגע הדבר כמדובר

The Kli Yakar does something similar to this, saying he took his claim against Moshe, namely his status as בן יצהר; he also mentions the vestigial vav idea, and that midrash about the טלית of תכלת.

Answer (score 4):

Rashi gives two interpretations:

1. (Following Onkelos) Korach separated himself from the community, he “took” himself to one side.
2. Korach persuaded the leaders to join his movement, he “took” them in to his group.

Answer (score 2):

RaSHbaM who commented on a very pshat level said on this pasuk that Korach took Datan and Aviram and the rest of the "rebels" until they were 250 people in front of Moshe. Very simple answer.